# All Possible combination of a string in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combinations

I am trying to make all possible combination of a string except the regular ones,

For exemple if i put on a `TextBox` `ABCDEFGH` i don't need `AAAAAAAAAA` or `BBBBBBBB` or `ABABABAB` or `ABCDABCD` and so on...

I need all possible combination but only randomly ones not symetric ones, for exemple: `BCGHDAAC` or `ACEEFAGH`... etc

Is there a way to do that? Because i really don't know how to do it

I tried this one but it's not giving me all results

```
 Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do Until i = TextBox1.Text.Length
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, +1)
            i = i + 1

        Loop

        i = TextBox1.Text.Length
        Do Until i = 0
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, +1)
            i = i - 1

        Loop
```

Thank you for help

Comment: If you want them random, and you want all possible variants, the correct procedure is to generate them systemically, and then shuffle the result. The keyword to search for is "permutations".

Comment: You're going to have to do a waaaaay better job of defining what you want versus what you don't want in terms of a valid result.  Some of your "valid" examples are using the letter `A` more than once, but there was only ONE `A` in the input.  If you can use the letters more than once, then there are an INFINITE number of possibilities...

Comment: You will get better answers if you explain why you need to build such string?